# Google Geocode API - Indian Reservations

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocode, google-geocoder

Why is it that no type is returned when the address component is an Indian 
Reservation? It is just returned as shown below, and because there is no type, it causes an error when trying to geocode addresses that return an Indian Reservation.

```
<address_component>
 <long_name>Hopi Indian Reservation</long_name>
 <short_name>Hopi Indian Reservation</short_name>
</address_component>
```

Example addreses: 
HWY 160 & HWY 264 
Tuba City, AZ 86045

OR

HWY 160 & HWY 163 
Kayenta, AZ 86033

Answer (score 4):

I guess the documentation about [Address Component Types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) is a bit too subtle as to (not mentioning) the fact that there is no guarantee that the `types[]` array will always contain something, or that hese types *may* also be returned within `address_components[]` arrays ... or may not.

Your example reproduces this behavior pretty well:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Hopi%20Indian%20Reservation

The `types[]` array is empty for the first result *and* its first address component.

Short term, I think your (and everybody's) code should be ready to accept empty `types[]` arrays. Long term, I'd agree it'd be better to give every result at least one type. For the specific case of indian reservations, I've no idea which one (if any) of the available ones would make sense. Maybe one of...

- political indicates a political entity. Usually, this type indicates a polygon of some civil administration.
- colloquial_area indicates a commonly-used alternative name for the entity.
- park indicates a named park.
- point_of_interest indicates a named point of interest. Typically, these "POI"s are prominent local entities that don't easily fit in another category such as "Empire State Building" or "Statue of Liberty."

If anyone has a clear idea how to classify these in the available [Address Component Types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types), please [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Geocoding%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) for the Geocoding API ;)